# Написать код в одну строчку

Tags: python, оптимизация

Как этот код можно написать в одну строчку?

```
    a = int(input())
    for i in range(3): print(a+i)
```

Comment: Можно все.. но сравните ваш код и в одну строку... А вдруг это потом читать придется...

Comment: Согласен, будет менее читаемо, но инересы ‘магические’ функциии питона=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for i, _ in enumerate(range(3), int(input())): print(i)
```

И даже одним выражением

```
any(print(i) for i, _ in enumerate(range(3), int(input())))
```

Но зачем?

Answer (score 11):

```
for k in range(a := int(input()), a + 3): print(k)
```

`:=` — оператор, допускающий присваивание внутри выражений. Присваивает значение переменной и возвращает это значение.

→ https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics

(для версий 3.8+)

---

---

```
a = int(input()); [print(a + i) for i in range(3)]
```

`;` позволяет на одной строчке разместить несколько несоставных инструкций.

`for (...): ляляля` — состоит из двух частей, поэтому не поместится на одной строчке с другой инструкцией. Поэтому использован сгенерированный список.

---

---

Немного извращений в придачу:

```
for k in range( *(lambda a: (a, a + 3))( int(input()) ) ): print(k)
```

`lambda a: (a, a + 3)` — Функция, возвращает кортеж из двух чисел.

`(lambda a: (a, a + 3))( int(input()) )` — сразу же вызывается с аргументом `int(input())`, параметр `a` получает введенное значение.

`*` — полученный кортеж распаковывается, элементы попадают в генератор `range` в виде аргументов, как если бы вызвали `range(*(a, a + 3))` → `range(a, a + 3)`